# Fuse Hidden file in Github Master

Tags: git, github, fuse

I was working in a branch 'A' and created a folder 'MyFolder' in this branch. I committed my changes but didn't push the changes to master. Then, I did `git checkout master` and shifted to master branch. Now, the folder 'MyFolder' shouldn't be there but it's present with a hidden file  `.fuse_hidden0000adbd00000004`. There is nothing else in the 'MyFolder' folder in master.

Can I delete the folder 'MyFolder' from master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.fuse_hidden` files are related to [FUSE filesystems](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/), and should generally get cleaned up automatically. There are [lots](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493198/what-is-a-fuse-hidden-file-and-why-do-they-exist) [of](https://serverfault.com/questions/478558/how-to-delete-fuse-hidden-files) [references](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?63743-What-is-Fuse_hidden) [for](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/issues/3) [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1771245) scattered about the web.

> Can I delete the folder 'MyFolder' from master?

You should be able to safely delete the file, and Git doesn't track directories. It is always "safe" to remove an empty directory in a Git repository.